# Cognos BI Icons and Meanings

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-bi

I'm looking for a list of all the Icons used within Cognos BI and their meanings.

Right now I'm specifically struggling with the blue Package Icons. I have two different blue icons:

- Solid Blue
- Blue with 3 small squares

[image]

What is the difference between these two blue package icons?
Where can I find a complete list of icons and their associated meanings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solid Blue Icon: Package
Blue Icon with Squares: Advisor Package